# C# calling C++-CLI dll - not sure if function parameters are correct

Tags: c#, c++-cli

From the c# world I want to pass in a reference to a List object into a c++-CLI dll. The namespace of the c++-cli dll is MatsWrapper. Contact is a managed object.

```
        List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
        String str = "C:\\DATA20110524064.h5";
        MatsWrapper.Class1 cl = new MatsWrapper.Class1();
        cl.CallMats(str, ref contactList);
```

Does my c++-cli dll function have the right signature?

```
int MatsWrapper::Class1::CallMats(String^ file_path, std::list<Contact>^ contactList)
{

}
```

I can't test it for myself because I don't know how to access to the Contact object in c++-cli. But when I find out how to access it, will my signature agree with the way C# is calling CallMats?
thanks,
sb

Comment: The Contact class is it a native class ? or a managed one ? (can you share its code ?)

Answer (score 1):

Your C++/CLI function needs to take a List < Contact > ^, not an STL-list. But your compiler should have pointed that out. With C++/CLI, your interface functions should only consist of managed types. After all, that's the point of C++/CLI, interfacing with managed code.

Comment: thank you nvoigt. C++-cli doesn't recognize List. says Liast is not a Template. I added

Comment: @JoJoAndChickie List<T> is in System::Collections::Generic, so you need to add a **using** declaration for that.